# Which language to use for my cross platform project?

Tags: android, ios, windows, cross-platform

I've been set a project to design an application for customers to log support queries directly to our CRM database instead of contacting us by phone or email.

Ideally this needs to be cross platform with windows being the primary but they'd also like iOS and Android for phones and tablets.

What do you think the best language would be for a cross platform project like this?

I have a little experience with JavaScript and C# but this is a long term project so am happy to look at other languages if more suitable.

Comment: Rather than 3 different native apps I would make a website that can be accessed from any browser (Windows, iOS, Android). Language whatever you are comfortable making a website in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Ken Wolf is probably the best option in your situation. In order to create native apps for 3 different platforms, you would have to learn at least 4-5 languages and frameworks, where you could probably instead just create a mobile-friendly website that can be accessed from each platform. Since you only need to make one website, you don't need to learn languages for each platform; you simply need to learn enough languages to make the website.

With regard to making a website for performing a set of tasks where the user can:

1) Access the service from Windows/Android/iOS

2) Log support queries directly to CRM

3) Log in using credentials(?)

You will need to be able to write a web app, likely using the languages HTML, CSS, one of either JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby or other (your choice of web OOP language), and perhaps a query language like SQL to access database information. Additionally, you will have to check out the API for whichever CRM you are using to see if they allow you to make direct changes to the CRM through your web application, and what that would entail.

You will NOT be able to perform all of this with one language as you mentioned, and will definitely need to learn multiple in order to complete the task.

Hopefully this helps. You will need to do a lot of research in order to make this happen.